# Changing root to new hard Disk partition breaks grub

Tags: grub

My root partition was on `/dev/sda1` and I changed the root partition to `/dev/sda2`. I updated the entry in `/etc/fstab` with the UUID of `/dev/sda2`.

But, I am not sure, how would the grub know that the root partition has changed to the new UUID i.e. `/dev/sda2`? Where else should changes be made apart from `/etc/fstab`, so that the grub can locate the root partition and hence boot the system?

Since, I want to learn stuff, I would also like to know the steps other than a simple command update-grub.

Do I have to change things somewhere else?

I am just running Linux.

Comment: Interesting to get a downvote without any explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using grub2, the most important configuration file is `grub.cfg` (usually located in `/boot/grub` directory for bios based systems and `/boot/efi/EFI/<os name>/` for efi systems). When computer starts grub follows instructions from that file. This is just a text file, so you can edit it by hand, or use some automatic tool (a shell script) `grub-mkconfig` (a.k.a. `grub2-mkconfig`) which creates configuration according to rules defined in a `/etc/default/grub` file and `/etc/grub.d/` directory.

Anyway, if you've changed root partition there are a few things to take care of. First of all linux kernel parameters: grub directly is not affected by root partition, but it needs to pass correct path to the kernel, so look for a line like this

```
linux /vmlinuz-4.19.5 root=/dev/sda1
```

and change it to `/dev/sda2`.

It can also be passed in UUID way:

```
linux /vmlinuz-4.19.5 root=UUID=abcdefgh-ijkl-mnop-qrst-uvwxyz
```

You can test your root UUID with grub's command:

```
grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /
```

---

Second thing to check/change is a kernel file itself. It can reside on separate partition (usually `/boot`), or on root (`/`) one. In later case you need to search for a line

```
set root='hd0,gpt1'
```

and change `gpt1` to `gpt2`. (I assumed here that you have only one disk `hd0` and you are using GUID partition table, a standard nowadays).

Depending on you configuration you may also need to change filesystem UUID and a hint string to find proper path to the kernel. It could look like

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,gpt1' --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  abcd-efgh
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root abcd-efgh
```

New UUID you already know, use `grub-probe --target=hints_string /` to find proper value of hints-string.

Comment: For what it's worth, on EFI installations grub.cfg is located under: /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg (in my case I use fedora, but insert your distro there).  The command would also be grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg.  Great answer though! :)